# Proper code design to use CLLocationManager in Swift

Tags: ios, singleton, cllocationmanager

So basic question.

As per documentation, I can listen for major location change using the API `startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges` on `CLLocationManager` class. Now as per doc, this API will guarantee that my app gets a callback when the user location has changed significantly even when my app is suspended. All good till this.
Now what i really want to do is to stop listening for updates if I received the callback at least once. Let's say I call `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, how does the framework know that I intend to stop a listener that I had set up before my app was suspended and eventually garbage collected.

On Android, generally each registration to a framework service is tied with the App identifier. So it does not matter how many times the app has been killed or restarted intermittently, when the app calls unregister, the framework basically unregisters the app and not an instance of it running.

This is a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same on iOS. The OS uses your app's bundle ID (Which must be unique) to keep track of your app's request for location updates. If you call `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` the OS stops doing so. It is the installation of your app on the device that's affected, not the current instance of the app that's running when you make the call. (On iOS the same app can't run multiple instances, so that's not an issue.)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. Can you kindly point me to any Apple documentation which states the above facts (Not that I don't believe you :) )

Comment: I just did some looking and can't find what I told you spelled out. It is implied by what it says about `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` though.

Comment: No worries. Even I could not find it in the first place.